# Calculate average value on objects with differing time delta's

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, backbone.js, statistics

I have a big list of objects (more specifically Backbone Models), with a value and a time. Simplified my objects look like this:

```
{
    "time": {moment.js object},
    "value": {float value}
}
```

The time between different objects is not always the same, so I can't just loop through all objects, add them together and divide that by the number of objects.

How do I calculate a correct average over this data?

Comment: `The time between different objects is not always the same, so I can't just loop through all objects, add them together and divide that by the number of objects.` Why not? Please explain more.

Comment: I am calculating the average temperature for a day. It might be that I have 2 very high temperatures very close to eachother (say, one hour difference), followed by two "normal" temperatures very far from eachother (say, 10 hours). Just adding all values up and dividing by 4 will cause distortion, and will end up with way higher average temperatures than what actually happened. This is because that would give the same weight to a really small period in which the temperature was too high, as to the really long period in which the temperature was normal.

Comment: So, you're not really looking for the "average" of your data, not how "[average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average)" is defined. So why not go through the data first and remove such points (`reduce` by time difference) and then calculate the average?

Comment: If that is a too simple model for your data (unknown) then perhaps take a look at how to analyse an [`Unevenly spaced time series`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unevenly_spaced_time_series)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is how you interpret the "holes" between the observations. If you agree that between the points temperature was equal to the average of these two observations (change was linear) this might be solution:

```
tempObservation o0 { t = 0, v = 100}  // time, value
tempObservation o1 { t = 1, v = 120}
tempObservation o2 { t = 2, v = 125}
...
tempObservation on { t = n, v = 145}

temp = 
[ 0.5 * ( o0.v + o1.v)] * ( o1.t - o0.t) +
[ 0.5 * ( o1.v + o2.v)] * ( o1.t - o0.t) +
...
[ 0.5 * ( on-1.v + on.v)] * ( on.t - on-1.t)

average_temp = temp /( on.t - o0.t)
```

Comment: This looks like it's the solution! Thanks :)

Comment: This is the first, basic idea how to relate change in temperature to time between measurements. This imply linear approximation of temperature. You can also think about different functions; polynomial, exponential, a model with lags...